# Django-RQ API_TOKEN configuration to access to stats endpoint

Tags: django, statistics, django-rq, rq

I'm trying to retrieve some statistics from the django-rq queues and I'm having some difficulties to access to the provided URL from the Django-Rq [documentation](https://github.com/rq/django-rq#queue-statistics)

> These statistics are also available in JSON format via /django-rq/stats.json, which is accessible to staff members. If you need to access this view via other HTTP clients (for monitoring purposes), you can define RQ_API_TOKEN and access it via /django-rq/stats.json/<API_TOKEN>.

Well, I have defined a simple `RQ_API_TOKEN` just for testing purposes in my `settings.py`

`RQ_API_TOKEN = "AAABBBCCC"`

And I'm trying to access it via Postman but I keep receiving the following response:

> `{"error": true, "description": "Please configure API_TOKEN in settings.py before accessing this view."}`

I've tried to send the token in the headers o even a query param, but it still doesn't work as is intended to work.

Example URLS that I've tried with query params:

- django-rq/stats.json/?token=AAABBBCCC
- django-rq/stats.json/?api_token=AAABBBCCC
- django-rq/stats.json/?API-TOKEN=AAABBBCCC
- django-rq/stats.json/?API_TOKEN=AAABBBCCC

The same I've tried, but leaving no query param and inserting the token as a header with the same keys. Nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out that the correct URL to hit was:

`django-rq/stats.json/AAABBBCCC/`

Without any query param or header. Sometimes the simplest thing is the right thing to do.